# extjs cannot save state with character "

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I create tab in extjs, and set name the character (") and then set in state. Now when I reload the tab I get error. Here is a part of json when I get the problem:

```
..."dateRange_widget_"_5454545"":"s%585"...
```

So, the getStateId can not consist the character (")?

Comment: I dont know extjs, but try to replace " with \"

Comment: tried 'escape()' while setting and getting stateID? - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.String-method-escape

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a stateId with a quote in it ? This is an invalid caracter for an id anyway...